# Comment peut-on dire qu'une quantité devient plus grande si une autre devient plus grande ?

Tags: verbes, comparatifs

Par exemple, j'aimerais une bonne expression (ou plusieurs) pour :

> Le salaire moyen devient plus grand avec l'age.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

« Le salaire moyen croît avec l'âge. » (De [*croître*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/croitre), pas de [*croire*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/croire), donc attention aux accents circonflexes levant l’ambiguïté dans certaines formes.)

À noter, comme le fait remarquer Stéphane, que la formulation initiale n'est pas fautive ni incompréhensible même si je doute qu'un locuteur natif adulte va l'employer (je la vois bien dans la bouche d'un enfant par contre).

Comment: J'aurais dit la même chose, mais *augmenter* peut aussi faire l'affaire. (Et la phrase citée dans la question n'est pas mauvaise non plus.)

Comment: Pareil que Stéphane, _augmenter_ est plus simple et ne s'embarasse pas d'ambiguïtés circonflexées.

Comment: Bizarrement, la définition d'_[augmenter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/augmenter)_ semble mieux convenir que celle de _[croître](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/augmenter)_, mais c'est _croître_ qui me vient en premier lieu à l'esprit et que je préfère.

Answer (score 9):

On peut aussi utiliser familièrement le motif « plus X, plus Y. »

> Plus on vieillit, plus on gagne d'argent.
>
> Plus on est de fous, plus on rit.

À comparer à l'anglais « the more X, the more Y. »

Answer (score 6):

***Croître***, ***augmenter*** et la plupart de leurs synonymes acceptent une construction utilisant ***avec*** : « X augmente avec Y » pour signifier que X augmente lorsque Y augmente.

Answer (score 3):

*Évoluer* peut aussi être un bon choix même si il n'indique pas dans quel sens l'évolution a lieu :

> Le salaire moyen évolue avec l'âge.

Par contre, si l'aspect mathématique des choses est important (le salaire augmente dans les mêmes proportions que l'âge; par exemple), tu peux aussi préciser les *croître* et *augmenter* déjà donnés :

> Le salaire moyen augmente proportionnellement à l'âge.
>   Le salaire moyen croît en fonction de l'âge.
>   Le salaire moyen augmente en relation avec l'âge.

Dans la série « locutions inutilement compliquées eu égard à la simplicité de la question », tu peux aussi indiquer le lien entre les deux grandeurs en les liant grammaticalement :

> Le salaire moyen et l'âge augmentent de [conserve](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conserve/1). (ou de [concert](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/concert))

Ou encore, pour utiliser une autre formule :

> Le rapport entre le salaire moyen et l'âge reste constant.

Qui a le mérite — ou l'inconvénient — de forcer l'interlocuteur à réfléchir.

Comment: Attention, la proposition "Le salaire moyen augmente proportionnellement à l'âge" ne signifie pas la même chose que l'énoncé de départ. Par exemple, il est vrai que l'énergie cinétique d'un corps croît avec sa vitesse, mais on ne peut pas dire que l'énergie cinétique est proportionnelle à la vitesse !

Answer (score 0):

Le salaire moyen est **indexé sur** l'âge d'une manière progressive.

Exemple en situation:
J'observe que le salaire moyen dans cette entreprise est positivement indexé proportionnellement à l'âge.

Et si l'évolution est rapide on pourra dire *de façon exponentielle*.
Les mots *concordance* et *synchrone* viennent à l'esprit également.

Comment: *Indexé sur* signifie qu'il y a une volonté consciente, exprimée par la loi, de faire varier le salaire moyen en fonction de l'âge (ce qui n'est le cas dans aucun endroit que je connais — le salaire moyen peut être indexé sur l'ancienneté par contre). *De façon exponentielle* traduit une relation particulière, ou par abus de langage une variation rapide. *Concordance* est inhabituel pour une variation sur des ensembles ordonnés.

Comment: @gilles non ce n'est pas forcément législatif. Par exemple cet emploi existe sur les marchés boursiers. Je confirme *exponentiel* n'est valide que pour des cas bien particuliers. Ce qui te dérange réellement c'est le verbe être dans son exemple qui sous-entend que c'est toujours le cas.

Comment: @Gilles "J'observe que le salaire moyen dans cette entreprise est positivement indexé proportionnellement à l'âge." te plairait plus?

Comment: Certes, j'aurais dû dire *règle* plutôt que *loi*. Il n'empêche que c'est un cas particulier, qui est loin de convenir `a tous les cas où une grandeur varie en fonction d'une autre.